# Problem joining 2 tables

Tags: php, sql, mysql, join, while-loop

I want to join 2 tables together but i cant get it to work.

These are the tables:
**threads:** `id, title`
**posts:** `thread_id, message`

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT threads.id, threads.title
                    FROM threads
                    JOIN posts ON posts.thread_id = threads.id
                    WHERE threads.id = ".intval($_GET['id']));


while ($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    echo $post['title'];
    echo $post['message'];

}
```

It gets the title but not the message. I have one assigned to the thread.

Comment: show us a little more code including the definition of $id and $sql.

Comment: and please add a mysql_real_escape_string() around your $_GET['id]

Answer (score 3):

You're not selecting posts.message. Change your SQL to this and it may work.

```
SELECT threads.id, threads.title, posts.message
FROM threads
JOIN posts ON posts.thread_id = threads.id
WHERE threads.id = $id
```

Comment: thanks that works but not really how i wanted it, i have 2 records and it only loops out one for some reason :/

Comment: do they both have the same $id?

Comment: How could two threads possibly have the same ID? Your schema is broken if that is possible.

Comment: @blue: give us the exact content of your tables

Answer (score 1):

Are there posts with a `thread_id` that matches `$id`?  Because, if not, that would generate an empty result set.

Comment: Try removing the where clause and see if you get any results.  If so, the problem is as inkedmn suggested.  If not, at least you've just reduced your search space for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make it work in MySQL, without the PHP?  I rely on phpMyAdmin to troubleshoot queries.  Once I get it in MySQL more directly, phpMyAdmin has a "export SQL for PHP" feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the posts you might want to do it the other way

```
SELECT threads.id, threads.title, posts.message
FROM posts
JOIN threads ON threads.id = posts.thread_id
WHERE posts.thread_id = $id
```